# Android TabLayout textAppearance issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-tablayout

I am trying to use `TabLayout`, but have some issues with `TextAppearance`. Here you can see screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, the text size of the middle tab header is larger than others.

Here is my code

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2.9">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout_company"
                style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_company"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout_company"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And styles

```
<style name="TabLayoutStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/base_app_color_sky_blue</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">5dp</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabLayoutHeaderTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/base_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="TabLayoutHeaderTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_header_title</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/base_app_color_dark</item>
</style>
```

Without specifying `tabTextAppearance` it looks following

[image]

What is the problem ?

P.S. On some devices (APIs) there is no such issue.

Comment: What you do want your tabs to look like? It is not clear from your description.

Comment: I want text size to be the same for each tab ? How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Coincidentally, this morning I had a problem with RecyclerView text just being too large on an API 16 device and just fine on API 21 and later. This [support library fix](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) helped me, maybe it is something that may help you or, at least, get you started on a solution.